# sql select current images code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image, select

Here is my code

```
@$sql="select * from mp_images where id='5' and status='0'";
@$query=mysql_query($sql);
while(@$row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    @$image=$row ['photo'];
?>
<img src="image/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="360" height="150">
<?php
}
?>
```

I want to display current latest images after I have added it into database

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: @VivekSadh: How would the OP be getting an error when he's [suppressing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) them?

Comment: @eggyal Thanks for info. I never knew that @ is used to suppress error message. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the image of the latest inserted or updated record?

Comment: Please _don't use the deprecated `mysal_*` extension anymore_. _deprecated_ means it's no longer supported, and will be removed some time in the future. Switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Also: _never suppress errors_. They're still being issued (which slows you down) and debugging is made a lot harder. Errors are there for a reason, use them to your advantage. Think of them as a fire alarm: you can use earplugs to _not_ hear the warning and burn to a crisp, or you can get a fire extinguisher to stop the fire burning your house down. I know which one I'd prefer...

Comment: @Dinup Kandel I want get the image of the latest inserted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just order them by id

```
@$sql="select * from mp_images where status='0' order by id desc limit 1";
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for your answer, but I just want to show only 1 recent/latest image. Just now it show the list. How to do that thanks...